# how to open a website directly in firefox private mode using command line (cmd prompt in my case)

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface

I can't seem to find the command for opening a website in private mode using cmd prompt.

While I know how to open Fire Fox and sites on fire fox or even private windows, I can't seem to be able to do a site open in firefox mode directly, at least not without switching my firefox opening requirement to dark mode by default, which is something I don't want to do.

Is there any way that would happen. If you can kindly share a way I can, by opening a private window or if a private window is opened, simply opening it in that window and not adding a new one (similar behavior to the normal one)

Thanks

Comment: Didn't take long to read this page: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions

Comment: @JamesZ: nice, I didn't even know this was a thing.

Answer (score 4):

Open up your command prompt and type `start firefox --private-window "url of the website you'd like to open"`

Here's an example:
`start firefox --private-window "google.com"`

Comment: this is not working in the new version of FF

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS:

`/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin --private-window https://mozilla.org`

Apparently the URL has to have a protocol.  "https://mozilla.org" will work but "mozilla.org" won't work